# Is Kibana Watcher part of AWS

Tags: kibana, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-watcher

Is Kibana Watcher part of AWS Elasticearch open distro?

It should have been part of Stack management on AWS Kibana UI.

I donot see it. Would like to see if there is a way to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watcher is neither available on the AWS service nor Open Distro. It's an Elastic product (see the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-alerting.html)) and you can either get it on [Elastic Cloud](https://cloud.elastic.co) or by running Elasticsearch yourself ([download](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch)).

PS: Watcher is a commercial product, so you will either need a license or use Elastic Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can't use Watcher. But ODFE does provide Alerting of its own.

Plugin installation and configuration are documented [here](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/)